# maven - post-package phase is not running

Tags: java, maven

I have just started with maven. So please ignore if this is too basic to ask.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>debug</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Debug</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceExcludes>abc/**</warSourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <!-- Some work -->
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post.package</id>
                        <phase>post-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>This is not running</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The above runs succesfully and war file is created in target/classes but the `post-package` phase is not running. What is the issue? Is this because I have not defined `package` phase? If so then why packaging is getting done?

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: First you setup in your pom file looks wrong to produce a simple WAR file ? Furthermore a `post-package` phase does simply not exist take a look into the [life cycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). I don't understand why you need the maven-antrun-plugin in the generate-sources phase? Would you like to run the generated WAR somehow? For this you should use tomcat plugin or jetty where Maven plugins exist for ...Why are you doing a packaging exclude? And why using such an older version of the maven-war-plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because there is no such phase as `post-package` in Maven:

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) is the reference to Maven Lifecycle and its processes.

If you want to execute a specific task after `package` phase, you can preferrable choose

```
<execution>
    <id>post-package</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <configuration>
        <tasks>
            <echo>This would run during pre-integration-test phase</echo>
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: I need something after package and before pre-integration-test , I want to build a docker there, such docker will be used in a docker-compose that is already in pre-integration-test.